# Question about terminology of public key encryption in practice

Tags: terminology

I am asking myself the following question:

> Say Alice sets all things up so that she is the reciever in an RSA-system. What do you call this "network" now?

I hope it is clear what I mean. I sincerely do not know the correct word for that. I could think of something like:

- RSA-channel
- RSA-network

Could you please tell me. (English is not my mother tongue)

Comment: I don't think there is a specific word for this. Maybe "cryptosystem" is broad enough?

Comment: You could say it's an encrypted connection over RSA

Comment: Topologically speaking (Speaking of the shape) this is a star network. All information flow towards Alice, so it's a centralizing star network.